# Using Multipicklist value which is set in Visual force page in Test class

Tags: unit-test, multi-select

I have a multi select picklist component.

The MultiselectPicklist component implements a multiselect picklist similar
  to that seen when adding tabs to a Force.com application.

```
<c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Types" LleftOptions="{!allCaseTypes}" rightLabel="Selected Types" RrightOptions="{!selectedCaseTypes}" size="10" width="150px"/>

<c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Sub-Types" LleftOptions="{!CaseSubTypesForSelectedCaseType}" rightLabel="Selected Sub-Types" RrightOptions="{!selectedCaseSubTypes}" size="10" width="150px"/>
```

I need to write a test class for this.

In the test class how to set the variables :
    allCaseTypes
    selectedCaseTypes
    CaseSubTypesForSelectedCaseType
    selectedCaseSubTypes

I tried :

```
List<SelectOption> selectedCaseTypes = new List<SelectOption>();
selectedCaseTypes.add(new SelectOption('Ancillary Products', 'Ancillary Products'));

List<SelectOption> selectedCaseSubTypes = new List<SelectOption>();
selectedCaseSubTypes.add(new SelectOption('Vision', 'Vision'));

PageReference pageRef = Page.Case_Override;
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('selectedCaseTypes',selectedCaseTypes );
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('selectedCaseSubTypes',selectedCaseSubTypes );
```

but it gives error that invalid assignment of MAP(String, SelectOption ) to MAP(String, String)

Also I tried:

```
 ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('selectedCaseTypes','Ancillary Products');
 ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('selectedCaseSubTypes','Vision' );
```

But it is not helping.

I need to have these variable values from the VF page because they are used to update the case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `ApexPages` wants a `Map<String, String>` but you're passing in a `Map<String, List<selectOption>>`.

You need to either take the `selectOption` outside the List, or iterate over the list with something like the following:

```
 ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('selectedCaseTypes',selectedCaseTypes.getValue() );
```

Note the added `getValue()` that will return the string value of the `selectOption`.

Comment: It gives error : Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [LIST<System.SelectOption>].getValue()

Comment: Sorry, that's because it's a list of `SelectOptions`.  You either to to iterate over the `selectedCaseTypes` list, or not declare it as a list in the first place.

Comment: Nick If I not declare it as a list then my test class runs but without coverage for the code under consideration.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem then.  Without know your test class or code it's covering, it's hard to provide advice.  If this solves this problem, perhaps mark it as the correct answer and start a new question outlining the new problem you're faced with.  Alternately, provide us with a bit more information...